# NullPointerException error on a final array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've been a lurker of stackoverflow for a long time and usually always find an existing thread that answers any question I have, however now I must ask a question myself as I have not found an answer for it.

I'm responsible for the AI of a Checkers game made in Java for a school assignment. I've designed it so that when the AI detects possible jumps it can make, it will check to see if any of those jumps lead to a double jump, and if so choose that move instead of a random single jump.

Here's how this is done:

1)Store the board in a "backup" variable (8x8 2d array of 'Piece' objects) and check if there are any jumps to be made

2)If so, call method "doubleJumps" which goes through each possible jump

3)For each move, another method "speculateJump" is called which returns the new 8x8 board array that would result from the given jump

4)Then, doubleJumps takes this new board and goes through it searching for any more jumps, in other words double jumps.

However I'm getting a nullpointer exception to the backup array... and I've traced it down to this piece of code(with irrelevant parts removed) where it happens:

```
    private static int[][] doubleJumps() {
    final Piece[][] backup = BoardLayout.getLayout(); //fetches the board from the game
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {//iterate through board; all rows
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {//iterate through all columns
            if(backup[i][j] != null){
                if (backup[i][j].getCol()==colAI && PieceLogic.mustJump(i, j, false)) {//if the current piece is CPU and can jump
                    if (PieceLogic.canJump(i, j, i-2, j-2)){//if the jump is up left
                        final Piece[][] newBoard = speculateJump(i, j, i-2, j-2);//speculate the jump
```

at this point is where backup[i][j] suddenly becomes null. I can't understand why it's doing this because the method speculateJumps makes no references whatsoever to the array 'backup'. This only happens if I make any call to speculateJumps, otherwise the backup array remains intact. Here is the code for speculateJumps:

```
    private static Piece[][] speculateJump(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {//this function returns a hypothetical 2d board array that results from a given jump
    Piece[][] board = BoardLayout.getLayout();
    int removeX = (x1+x2)/2;
    int removeY = (y1+y2)/2;
    board[x2][y2] = board[x1][y1];
    board[x1][y1] = null;
    board[removeX][removeY]= null;
    if (x2==0) {
        board[x2][y2].promote();
    }
    return board;
}
```

as you can see its completely independent from the backup array. One thing to note is that speculateJumps is in the same class as doubleJumps. I'm completely stumped by this. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: There isn't enough information here to diagnose this.  Please aim to create a [short, complete example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the same symptoms.

Comment: so in that line is the nullpointer happening?

Comment: You should be aware that final only protects the pointer to an object and not the values. This renders it pretty useless for most usecases and confuses unexperienced programmers. I recomment it only for fields pointing to immutable types. But there are different oppinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manipulating the `board` array inside `speculateJump`, which is the array returned by `BoardLayout.getLayout()`. Inside `doubleJumps`, you also have `backup` holding the (previous) return value of `getLayout()`.

My guess would be that `getLayout()` (which you haven't shown the code for) does not create a new array, but returns the same array every time. That would mean than `board` actually points to the *same array* as `backup` and `speculateJump` *modifies the actual board* instead of working on a copy.

I think you're misunderstanding what `final` means. A `final` variable is a variable which can only be *assigned* once. Although `backup` and `board` by themselves will never point to a different array, *the array itself* can still be modified through those variables:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
final int[] b = a;
b[1] = 4;
System.out.println(a[1]); // -> 4
```

If you want to make sure that `speculateJump` *does not* modify the original board (the array returned by `getLayout()`), you'll need to "clone" the returned array to make sure that you're working on a *copy* of the data. That way, you can modify the copy without affecting the original array. In your case, it's even trickier because you have a two-dimensional array (an array of arrays), so you'll need to do a "deep clone".

Comment: You are right, getLayout() is just a getter that always returns the same array. And I believe you are right about what's causing the error... my inexperience/lack of knowledge has become apparent here. I've made the following change to speculateJump: 

  Piece[][] importboard = BoardLayout.getLayout();
  Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
    board[i][j]=importboard[i][j];
   }
  }
hopefully that does the trick. Thank you for you rhelp

Comment: @user3527621 That should work, yes. Don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your question! ;-)